# Crawling images fails

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl images from a website with the following scrapy code:

```
import urlparse
from PIL import Image
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem, NotConfigured, IgnoreRequest
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.loader import XPathItemLoader
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http.request import Request

from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from mobile.items import Website

class MobileSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mobile"
    allowed_domains = ["mobile-store.ro"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.mobile-store.ro/produse/"]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"/produs/d+"), follow=True),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"/produse/d+"), callback='parse_item')
    )

    def parse(self, response, response2):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        next_page = hxs.select("//ul[@class='products']/li/a/@href").extract()
        if not not next_page:
            yield Request(next_page[0], self.parse)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@id="wrapper"]/div[@id="content"]')
        items = []

        for site in sites:
            item = Website()
            item['nume'] = site.select('//div[@class="summary"]/h1[@class="product_title entry-title"]/text()').extract()
            item['categorie'] = site.select('//div[@class="summary"]/div[@class="product_meta"]/span[@class="posted_in"]/a/text()').extract()
            item['brand'] = site.select('//div[@class="summary"]/div[@class="product_meta"]/span[@class="tagged_as"]/a/text()').extract()
            item['descriere'] = site.select('//div[@class="woocommerce_tabs"]/div[@id="tab-description"]/p/text()').extract()
            image_relative_url = site.select('//div[@class="ad-image-wrapper"]/div[@class="ad-image"]/img[@class="lightbox"]/@src').extract()
            item['image_urls'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url,image_relative_url)]
            #item['image_urls'] = site.select('//div[@class="ad-image-wrapper"]/div[@class="ad-image"]/img[@class="lightbox"]/@src').extract()
            item['pret'] = site.select('//div[@class="summary"]/div[1]/p[@class="price"]/span[@class="amount"]/text()').extract()
            item['url'] = response.url
            items.append(item)
        for item in items:
            yield item

settings.py:
SPIDER_MODULES = ['mobile.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'mobile.spiders'
DEFAULT_ITEM_CLASS = 'mobile.items.Website'

ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline']

items.py:
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Website(Item):
    nume = Field()
    descriere = Field()
    categorie = Field()
    brand = Field()
    pret = Field()
    url = Field()
    image_urls = Field()
    images = Field()
    image_paths = Field()

pipelines.py:
from mobile.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

The issues comes when I try to get the images url, by using the following code:

```
for site in sites:
        item = Website()
        item['nume'] = site.select('//div[@class="summary"]/h1[@class="product_title entry-title"]/text()').extract()
        item['categorie'] = site.select('//div[@class="summary"]/div[@class="product_meta"]/span[@class="posted_in"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['brand'] = site.select('//div[@class="summary"]/div[@class="product_meta"]/span[@class="tagged_as"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['descriere'] = site.select('//div[@class="woocommerce_tabs"]/div[@id="tab-description"]/p/text()').extract()
        image_relative_url = site.select('//div[@class="ad-image-wrapper"]/div[@class="ad-image"]/img[@class="lightbox"]/@src').extract()
        item['image_urls'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url2,image_relative_url)]
        #item['image_urls'] = site.select('//div[@class="ad-image-wrapper"]/div[@class="ad-image"]/img[@class="lightbox"]/@src').extract()
        item['pret'] = site.select('//div[@class="summary"]/div[1]/p[@class="price"]/span[@class="amount"]/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = response.url
        items.append(item)
    for item in items:
        yield item
```

Which returns me the page url instead of the image url. All other fields are crawled correctly. Any clues on how to fix this issue and get the image url properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the image (and the whole content of `ad-image-wrapper` div) is filled dynamically via javascript.

Dumping `response.body` in `parse` method helped me to figure out that the actual image link is originally kept in the `ad-thumb-list` list. So, try use the following for getting the image url:

```
image_relative_url = site.select('//ul[@class="ad-thumb-list"]/li[@class="first_item"]/a/@href').extract()
if image_relative_url:
    image_relative_url = image_relative_url[0]
```

Hope that is what you needed.

Comment: Modified with your code and got the following:
   `File "/opt/mobile/mobile/spiders/mobilestore.py", line 39, in parse
     item['image_urls'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url,image_relative_url)]
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 253, in urljoin
     urlparse(url, bscheme, allow_fragments)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 135, in urlparse
     tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 168, in urlsplit
     cached = _parse_cache.get(key, None)
 exceptions.TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: yeah, `extract()` returns a list, just get the first element if it's not empty. Should work.

Comment: i'm sorry, but it is not gathering the pictures url, in fact is not crawling any items at all, it is just throwing the exception above, any clue ? thanks

Comment: I've edited the code. Just replace your line `image_relative_url = site.select('//div[@class="ad-image-wrapper"]/div[@class="ad-image"]/img[@class="lightbox"]/@src').extract()` with what I've provided. Hope that helps.